# Не подключается js через clientScript

Tags: php, yii, yii2

В главной конфигурации пишу:

```
return array(
    ...
    'components'=>array(
        ...
        'clientScript'=>array(
            'packages' => array(
               // Уникальное имя пакета
               'imgPreload' => array(
                    // Где искать подключаемые файлы JS
                    'baseUrl' => '/yii',
                    // Имя файла
                    'js'=>array('js/imgPreload.js'),
                    // Зависимость от другого пакета
                    'depends'=>array('jquery'),
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

В представлении подключаю пакет вот так:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('imgPreload'); ?>
```

В yii/js/imgPreload.js прописан простой алерт.
Как ни крутил, не удалось подключить js файл.

Comment: В исходным коде страницы в бровсере есть секция подключения js

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разберем подробнее ваш код
Я кстати рекомендую не использовать данный костыль а реализовать через AssetBundle и подключить его там же где вы делаете registerPackage

тут нас интересует строка  `'baseUrl' => '/yii',`  где хранятся ваш imgPreload.js
исходя из этой настройки он лежит так
./yiijs/imgPreload.js
я думаю такого быть не может

Мои рекомендации, используйте алиасы для построения путей

давайте посмотри на то как создаются стандартные alis

```
  protected function bootstrap()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        Yii::setAlias('@webroot', dirname($request->getScriptFile()));
        Yii::setAlias('@web', $request->getBaseUrl());

        parent::bootstrap();
    }
```

на примере @web

```
 public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        if ($this->_baseUrl === null) {
            $this->_baseUrl = rtrim(dirname($this->getScriptUrl()), '\\/');
        }

        return $this->_baseUrl;
    }
```

Обратите внимание на то, что в конце добавляется слеш

вы можете использовать такие алиасы для подключения своего js как :@web, @webroot
Даже если вы положили его в ядро* как вы и указали изначально, проблем с доступом не будет